# How to avoid a 'where' clause affecting row ordering?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by, query-builder

I have a case where I do a `select` from another `select` and the order of the returned rows is changed if I add a `where` clause.

Example:

```
SELECT t.id
FROM (
       SELECT t.id
       FROM table1 t
       ORDER BY
         t.viewsTotal ASC
       LIMIT 20
       OFFSET 0
     ) base
  INNER JOIN table1 t ON base.id = t.id
  LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON t2.id = t1.secondTableId
# WHERE t2.someBoolColumn = FALSE
;
```

Now, the order is the same for the inner `select` and the outer `select`, but if I uncomment the `where` condition, the outer `select` will change the ordering.

How can I prevent this from happening?

Lets assume the following for a given example:

1. I can not do one `select`.
2. I do not know what order has been applied to an inner `select` when doing an outer `select`. So, if I order from a joined table, I wouldn't know that I need to join it here.

#### More info on my use case

There is a query builder that provides inner select, and it may apply order by a third table that is joined to that inner select, if i would like to apply the same order i would need to know what tables were joined, and in the case of this poor query builder i do not have that knowledge

Comment: Apply an `ORDER BY` on the outer `SELECT`.

Comment: @RemyLebeau this is problematic couse i do not know the applied order from an inner select and in case of ordering by any joins i would have to join this tables on the outer seelct as well and i do not have the knowlage in the outer select stage about it

Comment: There's is no 'rows order', unless you use an ORDER BY clause. It's undefined. Anything can affect it.

Comment: @Vardius: I don't understand what you are referring to. The inner `select` orders rows a certain way so it knows what to return. Any joins performed by the outer `select` doesn't change that order. The inner `select` simply returns some rows, and the outer `select` then filters some of them out if you uncomment the `where`. It should also order the remaining rows however it wants. So there is no reason NOT to use an `ORDER BY` on the outer `select`, regardless of how the inner `select` ordered the initial rows.

Comment: @RemyLebeau There is a query builder that provides inner select, and it may apply order by a third table that is joined to that inner select, if i would like to apply the same order i would need to know what tables were joined, and in the case of this poor query builder i do not have that knowledge

Comment: @Vardius: The outer `select` cannot know the order of the inner `select`, unless you hard-code everything so both `select`s use the same ordering criteria. Which you seem not to know. So the outer `select` needs its own `ORDER BY` to order the final result however it wants, regardless of how the inner `select` ordered.

Comment: I know that but the answer I am looking for is how to have the same order here not knowing the inner order by, if it is impossible then this is the answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

tl;dr  If you want a particular order in your result set, use `ORDER BY`.

The ordering of rows in a result set from any RDMS server without an `ORDER BY` clause is formally **unpredictable.** Unpredictable is like random, except worse. Random ordering implies you'll get your rows in a different order every time you run the query. Truly random ordering, if it existed, would make it hard for simple unit tests to pass when your assumptions about ordering fail.

Unpredictable means **you'll get them in the same order, until you don't.**  That means your unit tests will pass, and your system tests will pass, and your system will fail six months into production, if it depends on result set ordering.

Why is this so?  A server's query planner is free to use any algorithm at its disposal to satisfy the queries you give it. These algorithms work differently for different types of table and different sizes of table. If you don't constrain the query planner by specifying the result set ordering, it may pick some algorithm that gives an ordering that appears strange to you the programmer.

Query planners have, literally, thousands of programmer years' worth of optimizations built in to them.

For people used to the procedural ways of thinking encouraged by all kinds of programming languages, it's sometimes hard to switch your thinking to the declarative / descriptive mode used by SQL.  With SQL (at least clean SQL without stuff like `SELECT @a := @a+1` and other hacks) you're simply describing the result set you want. The server generates results matching your specification.

Comment: If you aren't specifying an order, not only can the database server pick an unexpected order, but it can also change the order from one query to the next. (Possibly as tables grow/shrink, but also possibly just because the server changed its mind.)

Comment: Right. Query planning can depend on anything.  Data cached from previous queries? Yes. (mis)estimation of index cardinality? Yes. Current position of read heads on a disk drive? Yes (but I don't think MySQL is that smart).

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you not rely on the implicit ordering produced my SQL (because there is no implicit ordering as per Bohemian's comment). Rather, you should use an ORDER BY statement and select one of your columns in the query by which you should order your results. That way you can ensure that the results are always presented in the same way regardless of the WHERE clauses.

Comment: This answer is incorrect, or at best misleading, because **there is no implicit ordering**. You can't "rely" on something that doesn't exist.